# Remove ztemtEVDO_1.1.8-0sue1_i386

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

in the first, i try t install this software "ztemtEVDO_1.1.8-0sue1_i386"

but it's give this error, and then now i want to remove it's from Ubuntu  software center
but it's give me this error

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 122729 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing ztemtevdo ...

ztemtvcdromd: no process found

dpkg: error processing ztemtevdo (--remove):

 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 ztemtevdo
```

how i can remove this application?
this application really annoyin me, make me cannot uninstall the other application.

thx

Comment: Sorry, it's I'm wrong asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably ztemtevdo removal script is expecting for a process called ztemtvcdromd which doesn't seem to be running.

A hack to fool dpkg and force it remove ztemtevdo could be that of creating yourself a process named ztemtvcdromd.

To do this you should create one:

1. create a file in your home directory called ztemtvcdromd, and write into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cat
   ```
2. set execution permissions on it (you can do this via a terminal running: `chmod +x ztemtvcdromd`)
3. run it (run `./ztemtvcdromd` on a terminal), and let it run (don't stop/kill it)

Now you should be able to remove ztemtevdo, since its removal script will find a running process called ztemtvcdromd and will kill it...